# Lambda in a VPC not able to access internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function which is in a VPC, with an internet gateway. The security group connected to the lambda has all the inbound and outbound routes open. The route table is also updated. The lambda is still not able to access the internet. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lambda in a VPC does not have access to internet. You need to setup **internet gateway** in public subnet and **NAT gateway** in private subnet with your lambda to be able to access internet. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html):

> Connect your function to private subnets to access private resources. If your function needs internet access, use NAT. Connecting a function to a public subnet **does not give it internet access or a public IP address**.

Also you need to add permissions to your **lambda's execution role** to be able to create **network interface** in VPC:

- ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
- ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
- ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface

Comment: I made a private subnet and attached a NAT gateway, but I am still unable to access the internet(I also attached this subnet to my lambda)

Comment: @BhargavaMacha Can you provide all the details in your question. How VPC and subnets are setup, route tables, security groups, lambda execution role, etc. Also what errors you getting exactly? Thank you.

Comment: I just realized my mistake, I didn't attach any internet gateway to my public subnet. Thank you though

Comment: @BhargavaMacha No problem. Glad its worked out. Acceptance of the answer would be appreciated.